# Why can't I save it on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The Google cloud IAM authority has Owner, Reader, Writer for projects.
Google Cloud Storage has the Storage Object Admin.

Google Cloud Storage bucket address and credit are also consistent.
But there's an error below. What do we do?

```
{ domain: 'global',
       reason: 'insufficientPermissions',
     message: 'Insufficient Permission' } ], 
  response: undefined,
  message: 'Insufficient Permission' }
```

Comment: Can you post the way how save object on GCS and how you send authentication credentials?

Comment: It is created by Service Account and sent as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) you can find instructions on how to upload objects to GCS. Also be sure that you follow correct [authentication process](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication).

Comment: @문득수 Cool, can you accept my answer if it was helpful and to help other members find the solution fast?

Comment: I successfully solved it by referring to the method you taught me And the reason I've been through this is because I found out that it was my development environment problem, erased it, and made it new.